# Two column layout per page with header and footer

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have set up a page for printing an alphabetic index. Each printed page contains a 2 column layout. I am able to flow the content correctly but I need to add a header/footer for each page. I also need to be able to change the footer content for each page created. The footer will contain a disclaimer and page number. The problem is that the column content overlaps the footer. is there a way to restrict the 2 columns to a specific size per page so that the header and footer displays correctly

```
<!--CSS -->
@media print {
    #content {
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    margin:5px;

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}

}

table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

<!--Page Start -->
<body>

    <div id="head">
        <p>This is the document header</p>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <?php
        for ($x = 0; $x <= 40; $x++) {
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$x-Term <br /> Description</td>";
            echo "<td>192</td>";
            echo "<td>10955</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";
        } 
        ?>

    <div id="footer">
        <p>This is the document footer <?php echo $page number?></p>
    </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: could you please check <td> closing tag.

Comment: closing tags fixed

Comment: Does anyone know of a solution or alternative application for creating this type of document?